# Building a function which return the last numeric value of a DF returns : 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Below is the function I made in order to return last numeric value :

```
def DerniereValeur(DF):
    for i in range(1,100):
        print(DF[-i])
        if DF[-i].isnumeric():
            ValeurARetourner = DF[-i]
            break
    return ValeurARetourner
```

Where DF looks like :

| FirstExample | SecondExample |
| --- | --- |
| 28.32 | 18.32 |
| 60.2751 | NaN |

### Output excepted

```
DerniereValeur(FirstExample)
> Returns 60.2751
DerniereValeur(SecondExample)
> Returns 18.32
```

### Error Message

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

### Debug infos

Thrown on `DerniereValeur(FirstExample)`

line : `if DF[-i].isnumeric():`

Where `DF[-i]=60.2751`

```
DF
Unnamed: 2             100
Unnamed: 3        100.5425
Unnamed: 4       101.01144
Unnamed: 5       101.97366
Unnamed: 6       102.27216
   
Unnamed: 1257     60.97918
Unnamed: 1258    60.568195
Unnamed: 1259    61.285896
Unnamed: 1260     61.92188
Unnamed: 1261     60.62751
```

Comment: @Nick I tried it too it still return : `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'notna'`

Comment: is this a pandas DataFrame object?

Comment: @enke Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dropna` on the column of interest and then take the last remaining value in the column, checking for `IndexError` in case there are no non-NaN values:

```py
def DerniereValeur(DF):
    try:
        return DF.dropna().iat[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return np.NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'FirstExample': [28.32, 60.2751],
    'SecondExample': [18.32, np.NaN],
    'ThirdExample': [np.NaN, np.NaN] 
})
DerniereValeur(df['FirstExample'])
DerniereValeur(df['SecondExample'])
DerniereValeur(df['ThirdExample'])
```

Output:

```
60.2751
18.32
nan
```